# Inserting data from one database to another conditionally

Tags: sql

In my MSQL server I have a first database with a table that contains `ID` and `Data` columns, a second database, which is a copy of the first, except the `Data` column is empty.

I would like to transfer data from the first database into the second, inserting into the row with the corresponding `ID`. I would like the query to look something like this, but I'm not sure about the syntax

```
INSERT INTO db1.dbo.Table (Data)
    SELECT (Data) 
    FROM db2.dbo.Table
    WHERE db1.dbo.Table(ID) = db2.dbo.Table(ID)
```

Comment: If the data rows already exist but the data column is empty you would need an update statement. Or you clean the table in your second DB and do a full insert.

Comment: MSQL? Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an update on your second table like that:

```
UPDATE 
    t2
SET 
    t2.Data = t1.Data,
FROM 
    dbone.t1 AS t1
INNER JOIN dbtwo.t2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

If your second table is empty you can "copy" your data like that:

```
INSERT INTO dbone.t1 (ID, Data)
SELECT ID, Data
FROM dbtwo.t2
```